# Scroll event is triggered even when removed and created new one in page tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on vertical pagination on a table which is on a Tab on a page, every time I switch to other tabs, I remove the scroll listener attached for vertical pagination when content hides. Issue is when I come back to old tab the scroll listener is still retaining its old position and it's triggering the scroll event when I load new data to the table.

Code :

```
$("id").scroll(function(){
         //code here
     });
```

Note : This works fine, when I remove the scroll listener before content gets hidden.

I'm working on creating a plugin for vertical pagination. Please help me on this issue.